# How to Change the Text "Goto" in dropdown menu in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

I have a responsive menu which converts to Dropdown menu when resizing the browser for mobile devices. By default there is text in the dropdown menu that appears as "Goto", after clicking on which the menu opens.
I just want to change the text "Goto" to "MENU". Please help.

for details ... visit www.iiift.com and try to resize your browser in desktop or watch it on your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

here is your code which include this word that you want to change

```
<select class="responsive_nav"> 
<option value="">Go To...</option>
<option value="index.html">Home</option>
<option value="about.html">About</option>
<option value="about.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;About Us</option>
<option value="whyus.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Why IIIFT</option>
<option value="message.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Director's Message</option>
<option value="courses.html">Study Programs</option>
<option value="courses.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;All Programs</option>
<option value="fashion.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Fashion Design Program</option>
<option value="interior.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Interior Design Program</option><option value="retail.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Retail Management</option>
<option value="fashion_management.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Fashion Business Management</option>
<option value="merchandising.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Program in Merchandising</option><option value="autocad_training.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Advanced Autocad Training</option>
<option value="catalog.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Brochure</option>
<option value="faqs.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Faqs</option>
<option value="#">Academics</option>
<option value="admissions.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Admissions</option>
<option value="methodology.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;IIIFT Methodology</option>
<option value="parents.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;For Parents</option>
<option value="#">IIIFT Students</option><option value="students.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Students Life at IIIFT</option>
<option value="http://www.iiift.com/shop">&nbsp;&nbsp;Students Online Shopping Store</option>
<option value="facebook.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;check live updates</option>
<option value="studentslogin.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Online Login</option>
<option value="alumni.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;Alumni</option>
<option value="apply.html">Apply Now</option><option value="contact.html">Reach Us</option>
</select>
```

as you see in the above code you can change the 2nd line

```
<option value="">MENU</option>
```

to

```
<option value="">Go To...</option>
```

if it solved click on solved or vote the answers ,,

Comment: I found a common.js file which has javascript code, but not able to change to fontawesome icon of hamburger. here is the code : function(){
  var $submenu = $(this).children('ul');
  var count = $submenu.children('li').length;
  $submenu.stop(true).slideUp(150+15*count);
 });
 $('.header_menu').each(function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 var html =
 '<div class="clear"></div><select class="responsive_nav">'+
 ' <option value="">Goto...</option>';
 $this.find('a').each(function(){
  html += '<option value="'+$(this).attr('href')+'">';

Comment: to change class of fontawesome icon :: <i class="fa fa-/*icon name*/"></i>

Comment: its not working ... it comes blank ... i came up with other idea to download the icon and use as img src..... can you help, how can i call the img here ..... in jquery

Comment: using img src is not a good idea you need to learn how to add fontawesome and how to include it into you menu ..

Comment: Sir, I am basic guy, who learned these on his own, I just need to call the image, which will solve my problem with just 1 line of code ..... rest all is done ..... its on urgent basis .... if you have any idea .. i only can request

Comment: first you should watch this video to learn more .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbcD6z5Y-pw and you will know the difference between them, ty.

Comment: Thank you for the video ... i just watched it, i have used fontawesome in my earlier editing, but here this is a common.js file being call by my index.html file. I have to edit the common.js file code which only has javascript function. I tried using the <i class="fa fa-/*icon name*/"></i> but its not working..... so I thought i'll call it as image ..... please refer to the javascript code in the above comment of common.js Sir.